# Replace a substring in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have three variables: string, search, replace. I wish to substitute the %search% in %string% with %replace%.

This works but needs hard characters.

SET modified=%string:morning=evening%

This seems to be answer in the forums but does not work. It simply stores the entire line at %modified%

SET modified=!string:%search%=%replace%!

Comment: That syntax only works if you use delayed variable expansion. Use setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the top of your script, or call your script using cmd.exe /V:ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` format is doing delayed expansion--the `%` variables get expanded immediately, but the `!` variable gets expanded only when it's needed.  I believe that only works in a batch file, so if you're experimenting directly at the command line you won't get the same behaviour as if you are running a batch file.

Make sure to enable delayed expansion in your batch file before using the `!` notation, like this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET string=This morning
SET search=morning
SET replace=evening
SET modified=!string:%search%=%replace%!
ECHO %modified%
ENDLOCAL
```

This will echo `This evening`.

Comment: Thanks. Enabling delayed expansion is what I wasn't doing.